# replacing special characters in string Python

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to replace special characters in a data frame with unaccented or different ones.

I can replace one with

```
df['col_name'] = df.col_name.str.replace('?','j')
```

this turned the '?' to 'j' - but - I can't seem to figure out how to change more than one..

I have a list of special characters that I want to change. I've tried using a dictionary but it doesn't seem to work

```
the_reps = {'?','j'}

df1 = df.replace(the_reps, regex = True)
```

this gave me the error nothing to replace at position 0

EDIT:

this is what worked - although it is probably not that pretty:

```
df[col]=df.col.str.replace('old char','new char')
df[col]=df.col.str.replace('old char','new char')
df[col]=df.col.str.replace('old char','new char')
df[col]=df.col.str.replace('old char','new char')...
```

for each one ..

Comment: Try with `df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('.*@+.*', 'replacement')` . I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702338/replace-string-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Multiple Values of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433569/replace-multiple-values-of-columns)

Comment: I think where I am having an issue is - I want to replace certain characters with specific replacements - not just all of them with the same or a space or something.

Comment: Could you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433731/17209725) @PorscheAdams

Comment: I still get the error  nothing to replace at position 0 -

Comment: Could you please provide us with a data sample? @PorscheAdams

Comment: Also Could you provide a minimum working example from your script? @PorscheAdams

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s=re.sub("[_list of special characters_]","",_your string goes here_)
print(s)
```

An example for this..

```
str="Hello$@& Python3$"
import re
s=re.sub("[$@&]","",str)
print (s)
#Output:Hello Python3
```

Explanation goes here..

```
s=re.sub("[$@&]","",s)
```

- Pattern to be replaced → “[$@&]”
- [] used to indicate a set of characters
- [$@&] → will match either $ or @ or &
- The replacement string is given as an empty string
- If these characters are found in the string, they’ll be replaced with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Series.replace` with a dictionary

```
#d = { 'actual character ':'replacement ',...}

df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(d, regex=True)
```

Comment: gave me an error : nothing to replace at position 0 -

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import re
my_str = "hello Fayzan-Bhatti Ho~!w"
my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', my_str)
print my_new_string
```

**Output:** `hello FayzanBhatti How`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i'm trying to replace the special characters with specific chars - not just remove them - so more like:  this is ?ust gra$$  - to  - this is just grass